# Irritating and confusing hosted applinks issue on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks, bolts-framework

All my hosted facebook applinks used to parse in my app using the bolts framework fine. I go to sleep, wake up and now none of my hosted applinks parse and my app crashes when trying to parse them using the bolts framework.

I have even tested a legacy build of my app on an older device which is archived and has previously passed my test spec's and even that now crashes? Is anyone else experiencing issues parsing hosted facebook applinks on iOS via the bolts framework?

**Error message:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x37419830'

Answer (score 0):

We had that same issue yesterday, but it disappeared by itself. Seems like Facebook might have pushed a fix already.

All the new links are working fine, and the ones that were broken are working after a reinstallation of the Facebook App (might have been cached by the app).